# Error : unable to obtain exclusive access to this record while posting the Invoices

Tags: apex, batch, cpq

I have build the custom logic to post all the invoices by clicking on Lightning Button. It retrieve the Invoice Run Id and get all the invoices that are in Draft stage. I am sending in batch size of 5 and posting it by changing the status from Draft to Posted. But when the invoices are greater then 50, i am getting following error in Error Log object
"unable to obtain exclusive access to this record"

blng__ErrorCode__c : TAX-101
blng__ErrorOrigin__c : InvoiceService
blng__FullErrorLog__c : unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

After that Invoice status changes to Post In Progress

Can anyone have idea why i am seeing this error. I read the debug logs but didn't find anything. Can someone help how to fix it?

Batch Job:

```
public with sharing class SR_CustomPostInvoiceBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    Id invoiceRunId;
    public string draftInvoices = '';
    
    public SR_CustomPostInvoiceBatch(Id invoiceRunId) {
        
        this.invoiceRunId = invoiceRunId;
        //query to get all draft invoices
        draftInvoices   = 'SELECT Id FROM blng__Invoice__c WHERE ' 
                        + 'blng__InvoiceRunCreatedBy__c =:invoiceRunId AND ' 
                        + 'SR_Incomplete_Tax_Status__c = 0 AND ' 
                        + 'SR_Invoice_Display_Line_Created__c = TRUE AND ' 
                        + 'blng__InvoiceStatus__c IN ( \'Draft\') AND '
                        + 'blng__TaxStatus__c = \'Completed\'';
        
        System.debug('this.invRunId' + this.invoiceRunId);
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(draftInvoices);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<blng__Invoice__c> invoiceBatch){

        for(blng__Invoice__c invoice :invoiceBatch){
            System.debug(invoice.Id);
            invoice.blng__InvoiceStatus__c = 'Posted';
        }
        
        try{
            update invoiceBatch;
            if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
                throw new DmlException('TestPostInvoiceException');
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('InvoicesinException'+ ex.getMessage());
            
        }
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so it's clear what is happening in it and the community can help you debug

Comment: The error is in line `update invoiceBatch;` ?  If so, then since the custom object is a managed package with namespace `blng`, can the vendor assist with this? Do you have other automation running on updates of `blng__Invoice__c` ?